# Converting an ASP.NET site into a SharePoint site using ODBC connection and not SQL

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-config

I followed this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/ASPNET_to_Sharepoint.aspx and it worked converting my ASP.net Site into SharePoint with a SQL Datasoure.

Does anyone know what i must do in the Web.config of my SharePoint site in order to make my ODBC connection SAVE?

My ODBC connection = SafeControl Assembly="SamrasWebOption4" Namespace="SamrasWebOption4" TypeName="*"

Regards
Etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I set the Trust Level to FULL in my Web.config of my SharePoint Site and it worked!

trust level="Full"